# Undefined symbols on template (all code already in header)

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, linker

I have a `.h` file with everything inside it, both declaration and implementation. I have a main class that is `DynamicArray`, which should have two classes inside (`iterator` and `const_iterator`) which are been moved out in order to be able to forward the declaration, because they need `operator+` for example, where the first argument is `int`.

Those are the declaration:

```
template<class T> class DynamicArray;
template<class T> class iterator;
template<class T> class const_iterator;
template<class T>const_iterator<T> operator+(const const_iterator<T>& iter, int  diff);
template<class T>const_iterator<T> operator+(int  diff, const const_iterator<T>& iter);
template<class T>const_iterator<T> operator-(int  diff, const const_iterator<T>& iter);
template<class T>const_iterator<T> operator-(const const_iterator<T>& iter, int  diff);
template<class T> iterator<T> operator+(const iterator<T>& iter, int  diff);
template<class T> iterator<T> operator+(int  diff, const iterator<T>& iter);
template<class T> iterator<T> operator-(int  diff, const iterator<T>& iter);
template<class T> iterator<T> operator-(const iterator<T>& iter, int  diff);
```

Everything is been implemented after it (this is part of code):

```
template<class T>
iterator<T> operator+(const iterator<T> &iter, int diff) {
    return iterator(iter.arr, iter.pos + diff);
}

template<class T>
iterator<T> operator+(int diff, const iterator<T> &iter){
    return iter + diff;
}

template<class T>
iterator<T> operator-(int diff, const iterator<T> &iter) {
    return iter + -diff;
}

template<class T>
iterator<T> operator-(const iterator<T> &iter, int diff) {
    return iter + -diff;
}

template<class T>
const_iterator<T> operator+(const const_iterator<T> &iter, int diff) {
    return const_iterator(iter.arr, iter.pos + diff);
}

template<class T>
const_iterator<T> operator+(int diff, const const_iterator<T> &iter) {
    return iter + diff;
}

template<class T>
const_iterator<T> operator-(int diff, const const_iterator<T> &iter) {
    return iter + -diff;
}

template<class T>
const_iterator<T> operator-(const const_iterator<T> &iter, int diff) {
    return iter + -diff;
}
```

However, when I try to compile, I get a linker error saying:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator-(iterator<int> const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
      iterator<int> DynamicArray<int>::emplace<int>(const_iterator<int> const&, int&&) in main.cpp.o
```

and some other linker error, all regarding the `friend operator` of the two iterators... what am I doing wrong?

SMALL CODE TO REPRODUCE:

```
template<class T> class const_iterator;
template<class T>const_iterator<T> operator-(const const_iterator<T>& iter, int  diff);

template<class T>
class const_iterator  {
public:
    friend const_iterator operator-(const const_iterator& iter, int  diff);
    const_iterator(const int* container, unsigned int position) :
            arr(container),
            pos(static_cast<int>(position))
    {}
private:
    const int* arr;
    int pos;

};

template<class T>
const_iterator<T> operator-(const const_iterator<T> &iter, int diff) {
    return iter + -diff;
}

int main() {
    const_iterator<int> it(new int, 4);
    it -4;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212583/discussion-on-question-by-berto99-undefined-symbols-on-template-all-code-alread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @bruno for for telling me where the problem was.
The `friend` relations were referring to a non-template operator, however my operators where template, so I just needed `<>` after the operators:

```
template<class T>
class const_iterator{
    friend iterator operator-<>(const iterator& iter, int  diff);
    // instead of
    // friend iterator operator-(const iterator& iter, int  diff);
}
```